# where is the nomination flag in ice stun request packet?

Tags: webrtc, stun

ref to this [WebRTC - TURN and ICE functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259429/webrtc-turn-and-ice-functions/37259934#37259934)
it mentions that:
"Regular Nomination The checks continue until there is at least one valid candidate pair. The controlling agent picks from the valid pairs and sends a second STUN request on that pair with **a flag** to tell the peer that this is the one that is nominated for use.

Aggressive Nomination The **nomination flag** is sent with every STUN request, once the first check succeeds ICE processing for that media stream is finished and a second STUN request is not needed."

here is the stun packet which I capture by wireshark, but it seems that there are no a flag named nomination flag, can somebody tell or any documents to ref, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your link to the wireshark trace isn't actually linked in your question.

But, I suspect this is the ICE extension to STUN for the `USE-CANDIDATE` attribute discussed in the [ICE RFC 8455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8445)

```
7.1.2.  USE-CANDIDATE

   The controlling agent MUST include the USE-CANDIDATE attribute in
   order to nominate a candidate pair (Section 8.1.1).  The controlled
   agent MUST NOT include the USE-CANDIDATE attribute in a Binding
   request.
```

```
8.1.1.  Nominating Pairs
   Once the controlling agent has picked a valid pair for nomination, it
   repeats the connectivity check that produced this valid pair (by
   enqueueing the pair that generated the check into the triggered-check
   queue), this time with the USE-CANDIDATE attribute
   (Section 7.2.5.3.4).  The procedures for the controlled agent are
   described in Section 7.3.1.5.
```

```
20.1.  STUN Attributes
   IANA has registered four STUN attributes:

      0x0024 PRIORITY
      0x0025 USE-CANDIDATE
      0x8029 ICE-CONTROLLED
      0x802A ICE-CONTROLLING
```

Comment: correct. The other post is a bit unclear, nominated is a internal state of the ICE agent and the on-the-wire signaling use the use-candidate attribute.